# How to apply ng class with a condtion statement

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular js and was wondering how to make an ng class apply based on a set of conditions. For example i want to have a set of dates using ng repeat and change the colour of the date if that date is greater than the current date. My question is how would i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{'testClass': val == 10}"
```

this will add class `testClass` to the element when val is equals to 10

Comment: what if i wanted to evaluate an say currentDate > Date    where the date is bound to a scope eg $scope.Date and scope.currentDate

Comment: So your problem is how to check that a date is after another date or how to express the comparison inside an ng-class? In the first case I suggest you to use momentjs and its isAfter() function, and for the second case you simply put the result of this function in the ng-class: `ng-class="{'testClass': moment(currentDate).isAfter(Date)}"`